# transform narrow table into wide in java

Tags: java, text-files

I have a txt file containing wide table of strings. I want to transform it to wide list of lists based on the ID column. The data is look like this

```
    Long format has 3 columns: country, key, value
  - M*N rows.
  e.g. 
  'USA', 'President', 'Obama'
   ...
  'USA', 'Currency', 'Dollar'

Wide format has N=16 columns: county, key1, ..., keyN
  - M rows
example: 
   country, President, ... , Currency
   'USA', 'Obama', ... , 'Dollar'
```

I want to know the equivalent of

```
    SELECT country, 
       MAX( IF( key='President', value, NULL ) ) AS President,
       MAX( IF( key='Currency', value, NULL ) ) AS Currency,
       ...

FROM table 
GROUP BY country;
```

in java!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make it a little bit easier with some Collectors.groupingBy() but a simpler version would be this:

```
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new String[] { "USA", "President", "Obama" });
    list.add(new String[] { "USA", "Currency", "Dollar" });
    list.add(new String[] { "Germany", "President", "Steinmeier" });
    list.add(new String[] { "Germany", "Currency", "Euro" });
    list.add(new String[] { "United Kingdom", "President", "Queen Elisabeth" });
    list.add(new String[] { "United Kingdom", "Currency", "Pound" });

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    list.forEach(s -> {
        map.putIfAbsent(s[0], new HashMap<>());
        map.get(s[0]).put(s[1], s[2]);
    });

    List<String[]> wideList = map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(m -> new String[] { m.getKey(), m.getValue().get("President"), m.getValue().get("Currency") })//
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("country, President, Currency");
    wideList.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s[0] + ", " + s[1] + ", " + s[2]));
```